# mysql create table DATA DIRECTORY does not work

Tags: mysql

my query is :
ALTER TABLE book DATA DIRECTORY = "/dev/book";
and executed it  but i did not see any file in '/dev/book' path.

can any one help me?
thanks !

Comment: I don't think that's an option
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html *The DATA DIRECTORY clause, which is supported with CREATE TABLE ... TABLESPACE, is not supported with ALTER TABLE ... TABLESPACE, and is ignored if specified.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think DATA DIRECTORY is works with Alter Query. You can set DATA DIRECTORY path only with create table query. More info [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-placing.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Stop mysql with `innodb_fast_shutdown=0`
2. In
   `/usr/local/mysql/my.cnf`
   add `innodb_directories="/home/mysql/new_location;"`
3. Move table files from current directory to new directory (as example: `/home/mysql/new_location`)
4. Start up Mysql server.